# random sampling of points along a polygon boundary

Tags: python, geometry

I am trying to randomly sample points on a polygon boundary made of arbitrary number of points. The polygon consist of a set of x,y coordinates. I would like to keep the original vertices of the polygon as well as add the randomly sampled points, and preserve the shape of the polygon as much as possible. As shown in this example, given an orginal polygon (blue vertices, left), I want a randomly sampled polygon with N=25 points along the original polygon's boundary (red vertices, right). 
[image]

The code below is my attempt at using a spline interpolation to do this, but the results from the interpolation ends up significantly distorting the shape of the polygon (making it rounder), especially if the polygon has a small number of vertices to begin with.

```
def single_parametric_interpolate(obj_x_loc,obj_y_loc,numPts=50):
    '''
    Interpolate a single given bounding box obj_x_loc,obj_y_loc
    return a new set of coordinates interpolated on numPts 
    '''
    tck, u =splprep(np.array([obj_x_loc,obj_y_loc]),s=0,per=1)
    u_new = np.linspace(u.min(),u.max(),numPts)
    new_points = splev(u_new, tck,der=0)
    return new_points
```

Is there a better way to do this type of sampling that would not distort the resulting shape of the polygon?

Comment: What is a goal of adding new points??

Comment: The goal of adding new points is since I have a lot of these polygons of different shapes and sizes, I wanted all the polygons to have the same number of points, in order for a downstream calculation to be done. That's the motivation behind the additional sampling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the perimeter `p` of the polygon (sum up the side lengths). Choose one corner, get a random number `r` in `[0,p[` and then "walk" this length `r` along the perimeter in e.g. counter-clockwise orientation and put a point there.

```
def single_parametric_interpolate(obj_x_loc,obj_y_loc,numPts=50):
    n = len(obj_x_loc)
    vi = [[obj_x_loc[(i+1)%n] - obj_x_loc[i],
         obj_y_loc[(i+1)%n] - obj_y_loc[i]] for i in range(n)]
    si = [np.linalg.norm(v) for v in vi]
    di = np.linspace(0, sum(si), numPts, endpoint=False)
    new_points = []
    for d in di:
        for i,s in enumerate(si):
            if d>s: d -= s
            else: break
        l = d/s
        new_points.append([obj_x_loc[i] + l*vi[i][0],
                           obj_y_loc[i] + l*vi[i][1]])
    return new_points
```